# Can't use Google auth in Playwright tests running in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions, google-oauth, playwright

I have an app with Playwright tests. To get access to the app, the user need to be connected through Google auth (it's setup with Next Auth).
When running my tests in local, I can connect to a Google account but when running them in CI, the Google auth page does not appear.
Here's my the step:

```
playwright:
    name: Playwright
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: db
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          - 5432:5432

    container:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.41.0-jammy

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up repo
        uses: ./.github/actions/build

      - name: Install Playwright
        run: pnpm install:playwright:deps

      - name: Build application
        run: pnpm build

      - name: Start application
        run: pnpm start &

      - name: Push database
        run: pnpm push

      - name: Run Playwright tests
        run: pnpm test
        env:
          HOME: /root
          TEST_EMAIL: ${{secrets.TEST_EMAIL}}
          TEST_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.TEST_PASSWORD}}
          GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{secrets.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}}
          GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: ${{secrets.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}}
          NEXTAUTH_URL: ${{secrets.NEXTAUTH_URL}}
          NEXTAUTH_SECRET: ${{secrets.NEXTAUTH_SECRET}}

      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        if: always()
        with:
          name: playwright-report
          path: playwright-report/
          retention-days: 30
```

What should I modify to make the Google auth work in Github Actions ?
What should I use as the value for NEXTAUTH_URL (in local it's `http://localhost:3000`) ? I may need to give the right to this url to connect with Google Auth